# How to deploy dash app to the web server with responsive design?

Tags: python, frontend, plotly-dash

I wrote a dash app that takes in various parameters and excel files from the user and downloads another excel file depending on the parameters provided by the user.

When I run this app on the my local port 8011, app layout looks fine, however, when we deployed the app on a live server, the app became distorted and the layout did not come out to be the same as when I run the same app on my local port. Is there something I can do to fix this layout problem?

**Local Port Layout**

[image: Local Port Layout]

**Live Server Layout**

[image: Live Server Layout]

I coded the app and tested it only on my local port using `Debug==True` and it looked fine but when the app was deployed on a live server, it was not the same. I could not try to fix it because I do not know the source of this problem and have no experience in web design at all.

***UPDATE :***

**"Hr" and "Br" elements do not seem to work**

[image: "Hr" and "Br" elements do not seem to work]

**After div elements, there is no next line (continues on the same line)**

Comment: It looks like CSS isn't loaded from your server. Check your browser's debug tools to ensure that CSS is loaded, if not, you need to fix it (serve it) from your server.

Comment: It looks like "Hr" and "Br" elements do not work and after every div element, the cursor does not proceed to a new line but displays the elements on the same line.